# ViewPager fragment with nested RecyclerView fragments using Android design support library

Tags: android

I want to use [Android design support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.sg/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) to implement the following UI:

1. Activity with a `NavigationView` for section navigation.
2. When a section is selected, a new (parent) `Fragment` will be swapped into the container space (`FrameLayout`).
3. The (parent) `Fragment` is always a `CoordinatorLayout`. In the layout, a `ViewPager` may be used. (*problem)
4. If `ViewPager` is used for the (parent) `Fragment`, it will almost always accompanied by multiple child `Fragment` with `RecyclerView`. (*problem)

### Problem

1. When swiping on `ViewPager`, it doesn't swipe properly (eg. not 1 page per swipe).
2. <del>RecyclerView items are not shown (at all).</del>

### Activity layout

In `Activity`, there is a `DrawerLayout` with `NavigationView` and a `FrameLayout` for content fixing as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

### Fragment swap

Every time when a navigation item (section) is selected, new (parent) fragment is swapped into `FrameLayout (R.id.container)` with the following code:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container, new ParentFragment())
    .commit();
```

### Parent fragment (ViewPager)

In parent fragment, `CoordinatorLayout` is used together with `AppBarLayout` and `ViewPager` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.test.nestedviewpager.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The code below initializes the `ParentFragment` with random number of pages.

```
package com.test.nestedviewpager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class ParentFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final int MAX_PAGE_COUNT = 5;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parent, container, false);

        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
        activity.setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) root.findViewById(R.id.toolbar));

        final ActionBar actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) root.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), generatePages()));

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager, true);

        return root;
    }

    private static Page[] generatePages() {
        Random rng = new Random();
        int size = rng.nextInt(MAX_PAGE_COUNT);
        if (size <=0 ) { size = 1; }
        Page[] pages = new Page[size];
        for (int pos = 0; pos < size; pos++) {
            pages[pos] = new Page("Page " + (pos + 1));
        }
        return pages;
    }

    private static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Page> mPageList = new ArrayList<>();

        MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Page[] pages) {
            super(fm);
            if ((pages != null) && (pages.length > 0)) {
                mPageList.addAll(Arrays.asList(pages));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mPageList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return new ChildFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mPageList.get(position).title;
        }
    }

    private static class Page {
        final String title;

        Page(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
    }
}
```

### Child fragment (RecyclerView)

In each child fragment, there consists of a `RecyclerView` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The code below initializes the `ChildFragment` with random number of items.

```
package com.test.nestedviewpager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class ChildFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final int MAX_ITEM_COUNT = 15;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_child, container, false);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyRecyclerAdapter(generateItems()));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        return root;
    }

    private static Item[] generateItems() {
        Random rng = new Random();
        final int size = rng.nextInt(MAX_ITEM_COUNT);
        if (size > 0) {
            Item[] items = new Item[size];
            for (int pos = 0; pos < size; pos++) {
                items[pos] = new Item("Item " + (pos + 1));
            }
            return items;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
        private final List<Item> mItemList = new ArrayList<>();

        MyRecyclerAdapter(Item[] items) {
            if ((items != null) && (items.length > 0)) {
                mItemList.addAll(Arrays.asList(items));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.bind(mItemList.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mItemList.size();
        }

        static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private TextView mTitleView;

            MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                mTitleView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.content);
            }

            void bind(Item item) {
                mTitleView.setText(item.title);
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Item {
        final String title;

        Item(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't understand what is wrong with the code written at all. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You should put the coordinator layout in the Activity with the NavigationDrawer

Comment: And I would recommend you pass in a List of Page objects to avoid the pointless array copy at `mPageList.addAll`

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for the comments. I would like to allow each (parent) `Fragment` to take full control of the screen, hence a `FrameLayout` there and `CoordinatorLayout` in (parent) `Fragment` which is to be swapped in during run-time. Any reason I can't put the `CoordinatorLayout` in the `Fragment`?

Comment: I suppose you could. But the toolbar is being applied to the Activity anyways. I assume each Fragment contains a tabbed Toolbar, so you could refactor that to just one on the Fragment

Comment: @cricket_007 That was the initial plan, but soon after I realized I do not want the Toolbar (or the tabs) in every `Fragment` that I decided I wanted it to be like what I did now. =(

Comment: I had a typo in that comment. I meant only one in the Activity, but if you don't want one on every page from the NavigationView, then that makes sense to optimally place in the Fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see a reason why the ViewPager would be skipping swipes, but for the Child Fragments, you should `return root` instead of the super call. That would explain why you see nothing

Maybe instead of `activity.getSupportFragmentManager()` try to use `getChildFragmentManager()` from the Fragment class

Comment: Thank you. The `return super` was a mistake of using template codes. That explained why the `RecyclerView` items are always not shown. Now I am left with the mystery `ViewPager` scrolling issue..

Comment: The Activity's FragmentManager may be duplicating the swipe on the ViewPager

Comment: Thank you, now it works! It would be nice if you could explain more about the reasoning behind `getChildFragmentManager()` in the answer. =)

Comment: Because you are using fragments inside of fragments. Pretty self explanatory